# How to disable these tips of clangd in vscode?

Tags: visual-studio-code, editor, clangd

Appears when I change the intellisense extention from Microsoft C/C++ to clangd.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EUkFH.png)

Comment: search your settings for `hints`

Comment: Found it, "clangd: Toggle inlay hints". Thank you.